# Portioning '?' values based on Normal Distribution

Tags: r

I have a dataset has more than 400000 observations. One variable has a lot of '?' values. Its factor table looks like this,

```
 ?       AA     BB     CC     DD    EE       FF      GG        HH
17082    247   1813    96     72    12529    49732   382188    9
```

I do not want to drop all '?' values, instead I want to portion '?' values to other factors based on normal distribution. For instance, while 'GG' factor should receive the most portion of '?' values since it has the largest factor, 'HH' should receive the smallest portion of '?' values. I cannot figure out how can I do that using *R*?

I want to allocate 17082 '?' values based on normal distribution, then assign them corresponding factor.

Comment: I don't get why you're trying to bring the normal distribution into this?

Comment: @Dason Perhaps the OP means to normalise the data

Comment: I cannot allocate '?' values equally since all of other factors have different count. I suppose that 'GG' should receive more '?' values than 'HH' factor does in this case. I cannot come up with any idea other than Normal Distribution. Any suggestion?

Comment: If this is just one (or a few) variable of many I'd look into multiple imputation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` like:

```
set.seed(42)
table(sample(factor(c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH")), 17082, TRUE, prob=c(247, 1813, 96, 72, 12529, 49732, 382188, 9)))
#   AA    BB    CC    DD    EE    FF    GG    HH
#   15    71     4     2   482  1884 14624     0
```

Or with a real dataset:

```
#Create your dataset
x <- factor(c("?", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"))
x <- rep(x, c(17082, 247, 1813, 96, 72, 12529, 49732, 382188, 9))

tt  <- table(x)
set.seed(42)
x[x=="?"]  <- sample(levels(x)[-1], tt[1], TRUE, prob=tt[-1])
table(x)
#     ?     AA     BB     CC     DD     EE     FF     GG     HH 
#     0    262   1884    100     74  13011  51616 396812      9
```

Or simple use your data without "?" for sampling:

```
x[x=="?"]  <- sample(x[x!="?"], sum(x=="?"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to assign all of the `?` values to the other values in the proportion they appear in. If so, just create the `prop.table` without the `?` values and rescale to the size of the total (and perhaps `round` for good measure).

```
x <- c(`?` = 17082, AA = 247, BB = 1813, CC = 96, DD = 72, EE = 12529, FF = 49732, GG = 382188, HH = 9)

round(prop.table(x[-1])*sum(x))
    AA     BB     CC     DD     EE     FF     GG     HH 
   256   1882    100     75  13008  51634 396803      9
```